# Default value in child select list disappears when parent select is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Jquery which appends the values of my select list, into a second second select list.

Jquery

```
$('#country').change(function() {
        var getid = $(".selectlist").val();
        $('#countryid').html('');
        $.each(getid, function(index, val) {
            $('#countryid').append($(val).clone());
        });
});
```

I have found that if I deselect items in my parent select (country), the option 'choose country code' in the child (countryid) select disappears.  How do I reintroduce this to my append, when var getid is empty?

HTML

```
<!-- Parent -->
<select name="country" id="country" class="selectlist">
     <option value="22">Japan</option>
     <option value="23">United Kingdom</option>
</select>

<!-- Child -->
<select name="countryid" id="countryid">
     <option value="">Choose Country Code</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append it before the `$.each()`:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
        var getid = $(".selectlist").val();
        $('#countryid').html('').append($("<option/>", {text: "Choose Country Code"}));
        $.each(getid, function(index, val) {
            $('#countryid').append($(val).clone());
        });
});
```

If you only want it when there are no selected items:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
        var getid = $(".selectlist").val();
        $('#countryid').html('');
        $.each(getid, function(index, val) {
            $('#countryid').append($(val).clone());
        });
        if (!getid)
          $("#countryid").append($("<option/>", {text: "Choose Country Code"}));
});
```